# Project won't start in NetBeans after reseting the IDE

Tags: netbeans

So I am creating a simple java web Application on glassFish server 4.1 with Java EE 7 Web in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2. Everything works fine, but when I turn IDE off and then on, after around 4 minutes nothing is happening, the programme still states projectName(running) while before it would open immediately. Same thing happend on the newest version of this programme.

On the Java DB database Process it states:

Wed Mar 08 07:06:55 CET 2023 : DRDA_SecurityInstalled.I

Wed Mar 08 07:07:04 CET 2023 : Web server Apache Derby - 10.10.2.0 - (1582446) turned on and ready to accept connections on the 1527 port in {3}

Note, that I translated it.

Comment: Could it be the problem with something I do or fail to do when exiting IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As funny as it sounds, all I had to do is change default project location from OneDrive to path on my hard disk.